# Exception Handling not working in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: .net, exception, parallel-processing

*Problem situation*

In my project I call into PowerShell to retrieve a list of organizations that are configured in Exchange 2010. Then I have to do something for each organization. Invoking PowerShell is *sloooow*, so if I'd to all the operations in sequence, it would take minutes. You can, however, create a PowerShell Runspace Pool and execute commands parallel, which saves a lot of time. So this is what I did:

```
public void MainMethod()
{
    var organizations = exchangeRepository.GetOrganizations();
    Parallel.ForEach(
        organizations,
        organization => 
        {
            try
            {
                exchangeRepository.DoSomethingWithAnOrganization(organization);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    );
}
```

*Problem*

This works like a charm with one exception. The DoSomethingWithAnOrganization method has a try-catch and can handle some exceptions. However, whenever an Exception occurs, it isn't handled by the catch in the DoSomething-method, but immediately jups to the catch statement of the MainMethod.

(Note: The catch-statement of the DoSomething-method is called fine if I simple use foreach(... in ...) in stead of Parallel.ForEach).

*Question*

Why can't I handle the exception in the DoSomething-method?
Is there a way to DoSomething parallel differently so the catch of that method is called if an Exception occurs?

Thank you!

---

This is the DoSomething-method:

```
public IEnumerable<Mailbox> Invoke(string organizationName)
{
    try
    {
        var command = new PSCommand()
            .AddCommand("Get-Mailbox")
            .AddParameter("Organization", organizationName);

        var result = Invoke(command);

        var mailboxes =
            from mailbox in result.Results
            select new Mailbox() 
            {
                Organization = organizationName,
                Name = (string)mailbox.Properties["Name"].Value,
                Identity = mailbox.Properties["Identity"].Value.ToString(),
                Plan = 
                    mailbox.Properties["MailboxPlan"].Value == null
                    ? null
                    : (string)mailbox.Properties["MailboxPlan"].Value
                    .GetType().GetProperty("Name")
                    .GetValue(mailbox.Properties["MailboxPlan"].Value, null),
            };
        return mailboxes;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        throw new Exceptions.ReportingServiceException(Exceptions.ExceptionType.Technical, ex.Message, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the try/catch in the DoSomethingWithAnOrganisation? Perhaps that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Is the catch block in DoSomethingWithAnOrganisation more specific that the catch in the anonymous method? The catch in the anonymous method will catch everthing as it is the base exception class.

Comment: @Colin: Thank you for your reply. I added the DoSomethingWithAnOrganizationMethod (here called Invoke). If an exception occurs in the Invoke method, it is not caught by the catch statement, so the error is not logged, nor is a ReportingServiceException thrown.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting? You also call Invoke with a PSCommand object, what is that? You are also throwing an exception out of this method which your anonymous method will be catching, so it is handling the exception and throwing a new one (which is what it will do sequentially too) so I'm not sure whether that can't be acting all that differently to the way it was before.

Comment: Okay - we were both typing at the same time.... I'll re-read with your additional comment in mind.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint into the catch statement in the anonymous method (in your Parallel.ForEach) what does the stacktrace show you. Where is the exception coming from originally?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I'm guessing that if the code works in sequential (single thread) but not in parallel (multiple threads) then you are getting an exception that DoSomethingWithAnOrganisation was not expecting (at least as a sequential operation) but is getting now you are running it in parallel.

You are sharing `exchangeRepository` between tasks (threads) and if that contains mutable state then it could be what is causing the issue. You can't mutate shared data/state between threads without synchronising access to that data/state with locks. Often you'll find that you can get much better performance by refactoring your code to work without shared state than you will by trying to synchronise the code - which is the bottle neck in multi-threaded code.

If you can answer the questions I gave above then I might be able to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The exchangeRepository class is stateless, nor is any data mutated. In this case the organizations are used to retrieve more information. The organization-objects are not modified in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the MainMethod to:

```
var organizations = ExchangeRepository.GetOrganizations().AsParallel();
var someInfo = organizations.SelectMany(organization => ExchangeRepository.DoSomethingWithOrganization(organization.Name));
```

and now the catch in the DoSomething-method IS called. I don't know why it does work this way and why it didn't the other way.